# Clear button NOT showing on UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm facing a problem while trying to enable the clear button on UITextField.
I have added like this:

```
if let clearButton = searchTextField.value(forKeyPath: "_clearButton") as? UIButton { //KV
    clearButton.tintColor = .nextWhite()
    clearButton.backgroundColor = .nextWhite()
    clearButton.setImage(UIImage(named: R.image.iconCloseRounded.name), for: .normal)
    clearButton.isHidden = false
```

The debug 3d image is attached on the link below.

Please, could anyone see where I'm adding this wrong that it's not being shown?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where do you initialize R

Comment: I have faced same issue as I have set padding for my textfields. Resolved the issue by referring https://stackoverflow.com/a/10274246/10005005

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your code, it is working fine.

But you have to make sure that in the dropdown menu for "Clear Button" there is something other checked than "never appears".

[Picture of that dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfo0a.jpg)

Or if you want to activate it from code use:

```
searchTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/320079/1898677