# Titanium UiTextField Clear button is not at all visible in Dark Mode for iOS v13

Tags: titanium, titanium-sdk

I have been facing an issue with `clearButtonMode` property of `UiTextField` in my input box. If I use app in light mode then everything work well but the moment I switched to dark mode that clear button is not at all visible in input box.

So, Just want to know is it Possible to add `backgroundColor` to that button for dark mode?
Or is there any possibilities to make it visible in Dark Mode.

I have attached the code and screenshot of my problem.

Here is text Field code.

```
 var checkField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: 30,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    right: 10,
    color: '#000000',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    tintColor: '#000000',
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    returnKeyType: Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
    clearButtonMode: Titanium.UI.INPUT_BUTTONMODE_ALWAYS,
});
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like it is a very light grey (when you set it to a dark backgroundColor you'll see the X again.
But it looks like it is native behavior:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124973
and you'll need to create a custom textfield image (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10274246/5193915) but that means inside the SDK.

As a quick workaround I would just create an image and place it on top of the TextField and move it to the right corner.

Comment: Thanks,  looks like lot of work to do if I change at SDK level. I think the second one placing an image would be good idea for me.